# vue click on parent button made click on button in childs components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have child components with buttons. Click on buttons call method.

[image]

In the parent component, I want to have a "Create" button. Click on that button will like clicked on first button in all child component. How do it in vue?

[image]

**SANDBOX:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-dew-zmsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `refs` to access all child components to be able to call a method for each of them:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld v-for="i in 4" :key="i" ref="childs"/>

    <button class="allin" @click="click">Click to select 1m in all childs</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
     click () {
       for (const child of this.$refs.childs) {
         child.changePeriod(0)
       }
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: wow it is realy good easy solution thx!!!  what other ways are there? example if change buttons in child component to checkbox and listen event 'onchange'...

Comment: All this depends on what data you use and where. If you have an array of items holding these checkbox states than it's easier to change this state directly in the parent component and see the result in child components automatically.

Comment: No in this comments, sorry. It's more likely for your another question and someone's answer here on SO

Comment: i want know how it do . can you send me sandbox to pm ? because dont know how right create new question :)

Comment: Look at https://codesandbox.io/s/young-pond-z784g?file=/src/App.vue